# Python 3 & Pandas - Creating New Rows in DataFrame but Empty DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate over an array and add items (new rows) to the dataframe. But when I I print out the DataFrame it's empty. I must be doing something wrong.

Here's my code:

```
sdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Question', 'Answer', 'Total', 'Percent'))
for i, data in enumerate(q_array):
    sdf.append({'Question': data.get_question(), 'Total': data.get_total()}, ignore_index=True)
    for answer, number in data.get_answers().items():
        sdf.append({'Answer': answer, 'Total': number, 'Percent': number_to_percent(number, data.get_total())}, ignore_index=True)
sdf.to_excel(writer, 'stats', index=False)
print(sdf)
```

Any suggestions on simply adding a new row, then adding data to the appropriate column?

Comment: Take a look at [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` is not an `inplace` operation.  You need to assign the results of append back to the sdf variable.

```
sdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Question', 'Answer', 'Total', 'Percent'))
for i, data in enumerate(q_array):
    sdf = sdf.append({'Question': data.get_question(), 'Total': data.get_total()}, ignore_index=True)
    for answer, number in data.get_answers().items():
        sdf = sdf.append({'Answer': answer, 'Total': number, 'Percent': number_to_percent(number, data.get_total())}, ignore_index=True)
sdf.to_excel(writer, 'stats', index=False)
print(sdf)
```

Comment: Coincidentally, as you were posting this answer, I tried that: `sdf = sdf.append()` and it seemed to give me the results I needed, haha. You're right, thank you very much for your explanation and solution.